# Converting Integer to Double in Haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers

I want to compound growth over a year but I don't care about decimal points, so I tried

```
take 52 $ iterate (floor . (*1.1)) 100
```

The problem is that the type of `(floor . (*1.1))` is `Double -> Integer`, whereas the type expected by the first arg of iterate is `a -> a`.

I tried a couple of approaches, but ended up tying myself in knots.

What is the preferred solution to keeping numeric types consistent across function application?

Comment: You can't keep rounding intermediate results and hope to get a correct answer at the end. Why not move the `floor` out of the `iterate` and do `map floor . take 52 $ ...` ?

Comment: @Fixnum fair point, it was just something I tried to run in ghci when I ran into the issue.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The usual way to convert an `Int` to a `Double` is to use `fromIntegral`, which has the type `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`.  This means that it converts an `Integral` type (`Int` and `Integer`) to any numeric type `b`, of which `Double` is an instance.

Your case sounds like you want to convert a `Double` to an `Int`, which I would recommend `floor` for, but you'll have to make sure that your input is a `Double`.  For this, you can use the `fromIntegral` function with

```hs
take 52 $ iterate (floor . (* 1.1) . fromIntegral) 100
```

However, this will give you inaccurate results, since you are truncating at each step.  I would suggest doing

```hs
take 52 $ map floor $ iterate (* 1.1) $ fromIntegral 100
```

Comment: I will also add that the latter expression will be slightly faster since `fromIntegral` is performed once, `(* 1.1)` is still repeated, and `floor` is performed only as many times as necessary, although an argument could be made to transpose `map floor` and `take 52`.

Comment: Equivalently written as:

`take 52 . map floor . iterate (* 1.1) . fromIntegral $ 100`